# How to solve login issue while sharing post on Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, ios-simulator

i want to share a post on facebook it works fine when i use iOS 6 but in iOS 5 and iOS 5.1 it gives an issue of login, when i login and goes to already authorised page and press okay button it pulls me back to login like this and repeats again and again on these two pages
[image]

when i press okay it gives back

[image]

```
 case 1: // facebook
        {
            if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController"))
            {
                SLComposeViewController *fbController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
                SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

                    [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                    switch(result){
                        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                        default:
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");

                        }
                            break;
                        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                        {
                            ALERT_VIEW(@"Successfully posted to facebook.");
                        }
                            break;
                    }};

                [fbController setInitialText:quotesss];
                [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
                [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
            else
            {
                DEFacebookComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResult result) {
                    switch (result) {
                        case DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                            NSLog(@"Facebook Result: Cancelled");
                            break;
                        case DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                            ALERT_VIEW(@"Successfully posted to facebook.");
                            break;
                    }

                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                };
                DEFacebookComposeViewController *facebookViewComposer = [[DEFacebookComposeViewController alloc] init];
                self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

                [facebookViewComposer setInitialText:quotesss];

                facebookViewComposer.completionHandler = completionHandler;
                [self presentViewController:facebookViewComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
                [facebookViewComposer release];
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2: // twitter
        {
            NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quotesss ];
            if([text length] > 135)
            {
                text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", quotesss ,@"..."];
                text = [text substringToIndex:135];

            }

            if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController"))
            {
                SLComposeViewController *twitterController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
                SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

                    [twitterController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                    switch(result){
                        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                        default:
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");

                        }
                            break;
                        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                        {
                            ALERT_VIEW(@"Successfully posted to twitter.");
                        }
                            break;
                      }};

                [twitterController setInitialText:text];
                [twitterController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
                [self presentViewController:twitterController animated:YES completion:nil];
            }

            else
            {
                DETweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(DETweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
                    switch (result) {
                        case DETweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                            NSLog(@"Twitter Result: Cancelled");
                            break;
                        case DETweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:

                            ALERT_VIEW(@"Successfully posted to twitter.");
                            break;
                    }
                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                 };

                DETweetComposeViewController *tcvc = [[[DETweetComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
                self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
                [tcvc setInitialText:quotesss];
                tcvc.completionHandler = completionHandler;

                [self presentViewController:tcvc animated:YES completion:nil];

            }

            break;
        }
```

Comment: Check that you are saving the Facebook token in NSUserDefaults or not. Which Framework you are using?

Comment: what is a token i don t know.can you guide me?

Comment: Which framework you are using to integrate Facebook

Comment: Show some code how you implemented facebook login and authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code i found that the problem is in this code coz in iOS 5 Facebook is not available in SLCompose only Twitter is available so your FaceBook is handling by DEFaceBook

```
            DEFacebookComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResult result) {
                switch (result) {
                    case DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                        NSLog(@"Facebook Result: Cancelled");
                        break;
                    case DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                        ALERT_VIEW(@"Successfully posted to facebook.");
                        break;
                }

                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            };
            DEFacebookComposeViewController *facebookViewComposer = [[DEFacebookComposeViewController alloc] init];
            self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

            [facebookViewComposer setInitialText:quotesss];

            facebookViewComposer.completionHandler = completionHandler;
            [self presentViewController:facebookViewComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
            [facebookViewComposer release];
        }
```

So go to your appdelegate and check this method that a valid token(`url` which contains your application, token format is `applicationURLSchema://"token"`) check it is coming or not in this method 
If necessary keep break point and go through the `FBSession` class then `handleOpenURL` method and find where error is happening

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
 annotation:(id)annotation {

 // attempt to extract a token from the url
 return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
 }
```